# What is wrong with my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am creating a simple tester page to test some other functions within my website. I can't get it to run. What am I doing wrong?

```
<p>
    <a href="#" id="addItem">Add item to cart</a>
</p>
<script>
    $('#addItem').click(funtion(){  /* Expected '(' or ',' */
    $.post('http://localhost:1969/AddToCart', 
           'SystemCodeId=WB&SystemKey1=123456&SystemKey2=123ABC&Cost=25.01&TransactionType=1&Description=This is a test',
           function (data) {
            document.location.replace('http://localhost:1969/');
        });
    }); /* Expected expressions */
</script>
```

Visual Studio keeps thinking there is a syntax error. I don't doubt it, but I can't figure out where the problem is. The comments are the errors that visual studio is reporting.

Firebug won't recognize the script either (doesn't show in the scripts tab). So I know there is a problem some where.

Note: I am using HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`funtion` -> `function` in line 5.  also to go to the root of your site i would use `window.location = window.location.host`

Comment: Oops! `$('#addItem').click(funtion(){` => `$('#addItem').click(function () {`. The reason for the URL is to switch to a different visual studio project.